# data_change using cl_gui_alv_grid - not reacting to Enter key

Tags: abap, alv

I want to populate a field when another field was edited. So this is the method in the implementation.

When I press Enter nothing happens, but when i double click the change applies.

Do you have any idea or fix? I am using the class cl_gui_alv_grid.

```
METHOD data_changed_finished.
DATA: ls_inr   TYPE LINE OF lvc_t_modi,
      lv_stbl  TYPE lvc_s_stbl,
      gt_out type standard table of SPFLI,
      ls_out   LIKE LINE OF gt_out.


LOOP AT et_good_cells INTO ls_inr
  WHERE fieldname = 'CITYFROM'. 
  EXIT.
ENDLOOP.

DATA:
  ld_REFRESH_MODE TYPE SALV_DE_CONSTANT ,
  ld_S_STABLE TYPE LVC_S_STBL.
  ld_S_STABLE-row = 'X'.
  ld_S_STABLE-col = 'X'.

IF sy-subrc = 0.
  LOOP AT et_good_cells INTO ls_inr.
    LOOP AT IT_SPFLI INTO ls_out
                   FROM ls_inr-row_id
                   TO ls_inr-row_id.
      
      ls_out-DISTANCE = '556'.
      MODIFY IT_SPFLI FROM ls_out.

    ENDLOOP.
  ENDLOOP.

ENDIF.


  lv_stbl-row = 'X'.
  lv_stbl-col = 'X'. 

  ld_S_STABLE-row = 'X'.
  ld_S_STABLE-col = 'X'.
  ld_REFRESH_MODE = 2. 
  
  CALL METHOD salv->REFRESH(
  EXPORTING
  REFRESH_MODE = ld_REFRESH_MODE
  S_STABLE = ld_S_STABLE ).

ENDMETHOD.
```

Comment: **Remark:** CL_SALV_TABLE doesn't support the edition of cells, and doesn't have the two events `DATA_CHANGED` and `DATA_CHANGED_FINISHED`, so you probably have used a trick to access the private ALV grid control, which is an instance of the class `CL_GUI_ALV_GRID` (and this one has the two events). So the question is more about **`CL_GUI_ALV_GRID`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I said in the comments, it's obvious to me that the question is more about **`CL_GUI_ALV_GRID`** (not CL_SALV_TABLE). By default the Enter key does not trigger the events `DATA_CHANGED` and `DATA_CHANGED_FINISHED`.

If you want this feature, you must call the method **`REGISTER_EDIT_EVENT`** and pass one of these two constants for a synchronous firing of the two events :

- MC_EVT_ENTER : the events will **always** be fired when Enter is pressed, even if no cells have been changed
- MC_EVT_MODIFIED : the events will be fired **as soon as** one cell is changed and either Enter is pressed or the focus is changed to another cell.